# Audit gRPC calls in Java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to create a `ServerInterceptor` to audit all calls to the gRPC API. I would like to compose an object with a structure as appears below for each call to the API. These called are all unary calls - a simple request and response.

```
public class ApiAudit {

    private Map<String, String> headers;
    private long processTime;
    private String api;
    private String protocol;
    private String requestBody;
    private String responseBody;
    private int responseCode;
    private String errorMessage;
    private boolean isDeprecated;
}
```

My challenge is that there does not seem to be a single place where I can gather this information. If this were a REST API for example, I could create a filter which would have access to the request and response objects, which contain all the headers etc. and could wrap the filter chain call in a try/catch to determine if there was an error etc. However, with gRPC all these different parts are somewhat disjointed. The headers are received in the `ServerInterceptor#interceptCall` method, the request object is accessible if I create a `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` and override the `onMessage` method, the response object is accessible if I create a `SimpleForwardingServerCall` and override the `sendMessage` object, and I can override the `onHalfComplete` method in the `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` and wrap the call there in a try/catch to determine if the call succeeded. How can I put all this information together into a single object to write as a single line to a log or to store in an auditing database?

Answer (score 0):

You should override each call you are interested in, copying out the data you need. Then within `onComplete()`/`onCancel()` you store the data to the database. `onComplete()`/`onCancel()` is always the end of the RPC (although realize that sending can occur after a cancellation, because processing the cancel is racy; anything after `onCancel()` is discarded by grpc).

You will be creating a (forwarding) ServerCall and a (forwarding) ServerCall.Listener. To store the data in "one place", you can simply have one of your objects reference the other one (e.g., a nested class).

Note that it is *really* important to make a full copy of the `Metadata`, since it is not a thread-safe object.

```
Metadata copy = new Metadata();
copy.merge(headers);
next.interceptCall(call, headers);
```